# SOAP call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, soap

I am new to JavaScript. I've written a Python code for the SOAP request, how this can be achieved in JavaScript?

Below is my Python code.

```
client = Client(url='url1', location='url')
security = Security()
token = UsernameToken('api_username', 'api_password')
security.tokens.append(token)
client.set_options(wsse=security)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) js package?

As a simple example from doc:

```
let soap = require('soap');
let url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
let args = {
    name: 'value'
};

soap.createClientAsync(url)
    .then((client) => {
        return client.MyFunctionAsync(args);
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```